# Find the shortest distance between points

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on finding the shortest route between multiple points.

The problem I have is there are few constraints. For example, area with green line cant be crossed. So it makes distance between (assuming each grid width and height are 1) point 1 and 2 is 11.

I thought there are some modules which allow me to add node and link to calculate distance for cases such as, going "2-> 5-> 4" or "1-> 3" etc.

[image]

It would be highly appreciated if you would let me know tools allow me to calculate it. Tutorials will be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Djikstra's algorithm for shortest paths: https://dev.to/mxl/dijkstras-algorithm-in-python-algorithms-for-beginners-dkc

Comment: You should represent your map as a graph, each white cell being and connected to their contiguous ones, then use some algorithm to solve the [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) are simple and effective options. SciPy implements some algorithms (see [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very general solution (say if your green area can be any width, shape or size, or maybe you want to have multiple green areas) you should take a look at the [A* search algorithm](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html).

Comment: A* algorithm worked for me! thanks!!